# Getting memory metrics in Apache Ignite using http request

Tags: caching, ignite, metrics

> I am using apache ignite 2.8.0.
>   i need to get following information about ignite cache by using http request,
>   1. reads per second
>   2. writes per seconds
>   3. hit per seconds
>   4. miss per seconds
>   5. average read time
>   6. average write time
>
> how can i get all the info by using http request (using http rest API)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get some of that using [cmd=cache](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/rest-api#cache-metrics) (and doing some math if you want "per second" measurements).

The remaining you may hope to have eventually via IEP-35, I don't see any REST support for it yet, you can file a ticket against Apache Ignite JIRA or start discussion on developers list.